# Present perfect or past simple choose rigth

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-simple

I have this exercise.

Choose the correct form:

> They **had/They have had** three children - I'm the youngest.

I chose

> "They **have had** three children- I'm the youngest"

because I thought they still have children.
But right answer was

> They **had**

Why?

Full topic is:

> My mum was born in Plymouth in 1948. 
>   When
>   she left school, she started work in an office in Plymouth. Later, the
>   company
>    sent her to a different office in Bristol,
>   where
>    she met  my dad.
>    They fell
>   in love, and
>    they got  married in 1970.6
>   **They had /
>   They've had three children - I'm the youngest.**
>   They moved / They've moved back to Plymouth again when
>   my dad retired. They bought a very nice house and
>    they lived /
>   they've lived there for two years now. My dad
>     just put /
>   has just put a greenhouse in the garden for growing vegetables -
>    he was / he's been a keen gardener all his life. My parents
>   made / have made a lot of new friends and they're very
>   happy in their new home.

Comment: There is no reason why unless more detail is added to this question. Both versions are perfectly fine.

Comment: i added full topic to clearify context.

Answer (score 4):

- Without the surrounding context, assuming you are just talking about your parents in general, I would say "They have three children," or maybe "They have had three children" if you want to focus on the process of *having* (giving birth to) the children rather than the state of currently having (being parents to) three.
- *However*, given that you're telling a story about your mother's life, the context is in the past when you get to talking about your parents giving birth. You're not saying "currently, they have had three"; you're saying "and then, after getting married, **they had three children.**" So you're saying that they *gave* birth at that time (simple past), rather than that by now they've giv*en* birth to 3 children (present perfect).

  - By the way, if you were telling the story and wanted to mention something that happened before the point you were at in the story, you would use the *past* perfect. For example, you could say, "They *had* often *dreamed* of raising a family, so they had three children - I'm the youngest."

Answer (score -1):

If the parents are dead the past simple is used. I would use the present if the parents are living: "my parents have 3 children, I'm the youngest. The present perfect would be appropriate in a sentence like: "I have had three children, so my body has changed over time." have had = have given birth

Comment: To the person who downvoted my answer: could you explain the downvote, please? I like to learn from my mistakes. Downvoting without explanation is of no use, to me or anyone else.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but the answer doesn't make sense with the given context. In this case, the "had" in "They had three children" refers to actually giving birth to the children in the past - not being parents to them before something happened, like the parents dying.